# Countering Shyvana as a ranged

Tags: league-of-legends

Ooof, Shyvana seems to be a bit overpowered compared to the rest of the champions.  Or, at least if you believe the complaints from all opposing players anyway :D

Typically I play a ranged character, such as Ashe.  I attempt to harass her, yet she manages to keep up and overtake me as I run away, even with speed buffs.

What are some typical methods of dealing with such a character?  I have even tried circling a turret in Dominion, yet still manage to get drained of health nearly instantly.

Comment: try to stay in max range, I ussually play against her like I play against Ezreal, Corki, Rumble

Comment: Play an op ranged champion like Graves ;)

Comment: I mention in the Q that I play Ashe, who is ranged...

Comment: Make full use of your w for slowing her it adds your q's slow and can be great for harrasing and escaping thanks to that and just focus on last hits dont over extend play defensive tower hug if need be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I played her, and I believe she is OP indeed. Very good farming abilities and a dragon form nearly always available.

However :

- She hasn't got any dash, so you see her coming (except for dragon form)
- She has no CC (no slow, no stun, no snare...)
- She has no native life steal
- Except for her "E", she hasn't got any ranged dps
- You can see when her dragon form is up

#### Classic

- You shouldn't be laning 1v1 vs Shivana with Ashe because she should solo top when ashe should be the carry AD on bot lane with a support.
- What I would simply do is "not push" and fight by tower to get your farm and xp without her killing you. When you can stay at tower range and hit her, do so, but else concentrate on farm. (Plus, if lane is pushed for her, easier for your jungler to come and gank)
- If she keeps up with you even with speed buffs, its because her "Z" gives her (30/35/40/45/50%) speed bonus. When playing her, the typical problem is that enemies just use a speed buff and run away, you aren't able to slow them (this is why `frozen mallet` is a recommended item) or dash to them, you only rely on your "z" to catch them, but they get to tower to fast and you have to abandon pursuit.

#### Dominion

- You shouldn't be fighting alone vs Shivana either. Ashe is not the bot lane pusher.
- Stay at max range, if you harass her, apply your slow so she can't run to you
- When dragon form is up, don't be aggressive Take extra caution and stay back, fight only near a tower that is yours.
- Ask your teammates for help to push / gank, a ranged carry shouldn't be wasted on solo laning unless for a gank.

#### Conclusion

In general, ranged AD carry shouldn't be solo laning versus fighters. If they however do so, they should be extra cautious, stay near a tower or have an escape plan ready and keep mana needed to throw all offensive spells when ally comes for gank.

Comment: +1 to what you've said, except I disagree that she's OP. If anything, her character design is inherently UP. If played as a jungler, she relies entirely on the lane she's ganking to do the CC and lead the initiation. If played in lane, she has a pathetic poke  and an equally pathetic gap closer/escape until she has her ult, at which point it's a one-time use thing. On top of that, with no natural way to regenerate health, she's heavily item and rune dependent. Most traditional top lanes will completely wreck her in the current meta. The champion spotlight vs. Wukong is a terrible example.

Comment: @TheQ : What you say about her weaknesses is all true, I've state them in my intro. My belief in her OPness comes from the games I played, she seemed never to die in team fights. I would just rush in and tank it all (while still good dealing damage), even in the game where we lost and I had less gold than opponents. But maybe this was just an false impression from my first games.

Comment: +1, What i think might help aswell is staying behind her... since all her abilities are kinda front centered. In her dragon form she does major damage infront of her. If you dodge the flame comming from her behind you'll be fine i think.

Comment: @Dalshim I realize you've stated those items in your intro, but I don't feel that she's OP as you've said, which is more of my argument. She has the ability to initiate teamfights, yes, but if you build tanky your damage is negligible, and if you build damage you're going to be squishier. The lack of hard CC makes her an underwhelming tank, and the lack of a reliable escape/sustain makes her an underwhelming bruiser. I repeat that I agree with EVERYTHING you've said, except that I don't feel she's OP, is all.

Comment: @RafaelCelerier: I think that's a good point too...in the video the dev says that her attacks all go frontwards at one point.

Comment: There's a difference in her damage being OP (her burst might be) and being a wholly OP champion (less likely).

Comment: You shouldn't be laning 1v1 vs Shivana with Ashe because she should solo top when ashe should be the carry AD on bot lane with a support.- Your assuming you have a jungle which isnt always 100% the case and your also assuming your team have half a brain when it comes to picks which definatly isnt always the case so saying this isnt 100% correct you may have a vayne or cait so ashe may end up to lane sometimes so this doesnt really awnser the question at all its ok to say ashe should be bot but its not always the case with picks you have to consider that.

Comment: @Cem22lp : That's why I said "shouldn't" and not "will never". I believe I still answered the question by giving all the advice on the following lines. If you disagree or think it is incomplete, you can point it out, I'll see what I can do to fix it.